# Getting error while submitting form data using post method in AEM / CQ

Tags: aem

There is a cq  page and in the page there are many component. In one component we have HTML form code. After submitting form data ,i need to set all value in PageContext and use these value in other component on same page.

To achieve this I have created component named "MySamplecomponent". and in put all html code as below.Also i have created a POST.jsp under same component. 
Mysamplecompnent.jsp code

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>

<%
    //String collapsed = properties.get("selection","");
    String collapsed= request.getParameter("testKey");
    out.println("value++"+collapsed);
String category= request.getParameter("skill");
out.println("Category++"+category);
pageContext.setAttribute("collapsed1",collapsed,PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);

%>

<form  name="form1" id="form1" action="${currentPage.path}.html" method="post">  
    <input type ="text" name="testKey" id="testKey" value="collapsed" />
    <input type ="hidden" name="pathValue" id="pathValue" value="myValue" />
    <select name="skill" style="display:block">
     <option value="1">Cricket</option>
        <option value="2">Volley ball</option>
        <option value="3">Tennis</option>
</select>
    <input type="radio" name="ravi" id="radiobutton" value="success" > radiobutton<br>
      <input id="SubmitButton" name="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="SubmitButton"  onclick="javascript:location.href='#'" />
</form>
```

After clicking on submit button  getting below error

Error while processing /content/myPage/

Status
500
Message 
javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No matching property definition: testKey = collapsed
Location    /content/myPage/
Parent Location /content
Path
/content/myPage/
Referer http://localhost:4502/content/myPage.html
ChangeLog

Go Back

Modified Resource

Parent of Modified Resource

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I believe you mean *PageContent* under *PageContext*. If you want to use Sling Post Servlet, you need to change the action.

`${currentPage.path}` refers to Page node and not PageContent node. Page node has pretty strict restrictions for properties and you can not put there any custom props, like *testKey*. So to make your code work just replace your `action` attribute with `${currentPage.path}/jcr:content` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery and AJAX. See [this article](http://scottsdigitalcommunity.blogspot.ca/2013/06/posting-form-data-to-adobe-cq-using.html).